# Error in formula and no data argument in R

Tags: r, svm

I was writing a code using sim with polynomial kernel. The code is as follows.

```
library(ISLR)
library(e1071)
library(randomForest)
library(class)
library(ggplot2)
library(GGally)

train = subset(wifiLocDat, Loc3 == TRUE)
test  = subset(wifiLocDat, Loc3 == FALSE)
set.seed(4343)
tune.out <- tune(svm, wifiLocDat$Loc3~wifiLocDat$WiFi1 + wifiLocDat$WiFi2 + wifiLocDat$WiFi3 + wifiLocDat$WiFi4 + wifiLocDat$WiFi5 + wifiLocDat$WiFi6 + wifiLocDat$WiFi7, data=wifiLocDat,       kernel="polynomial", ranges=list(degree=c(1,2,3,4,5,6)))
summary(tune.out)
svmPoly <- svm(Train$Loc3~., data=Train, kernel="polynomial",coef0=1,degree = 3)
```

dput(head(wifiLocDat,20))
structure(list(WiFi1 = c(-64L, -68L, -63L, -61L, -63L, -64L,
-65L, -61L, -65L, -62L, -67L, -65L, -63L, -66L, -61L, -67L, -63L,
-60L, -60L, -62L), WiFi2 = c(-56L, -57L, -60L, -60L, -65L, -55L,
-61L, -63L, -60L, -60L, -61L, -59L, -57L, -60L, -59L, -60L, -56L,
-54L, -58L, -59L), WiFi3 = c(-61L, -61L, -60L, -68L, -60L, -63L,
-65L, -58L, -59L, -66L, -62L, -61L, -61L, -65L, -65L, -59L, -60L,
-59L, -60L, -63L), WiFi4 = c(-66L, -65L, -67L, -62L, -63L, -66L,
-67L, -66L, -63L, -68L, -67L, -67L, -65L, -62L, -63L, -61L, -62L,
-65L, -61L, -64L), WiFi5 = c(-71L, -71L, -76L, -77L, -77L, -76L,
-69L, -74L, -76L, -80L, -77L, -72L, -73L, -70L, -74L, -71L, -70L,
-73L, -73L, -70L), WiFi6 = c(-82L, -85L, -85L, -90L, -81L, -88L,
-87L, -87L, -86L, -86L, -83L, -86L, -84L, -85L, -89L, -86L, -84L,
-83L, -84L, -84L), WiFi7 = c(-81L, -85L, -84L, -80L, -87L, -83L,
-84L, -82L, -82L, -91L, -91L, -81L, -84L, -83L, -87L, -91L, -91L,
-84L, -88L, -84L), Loc3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label =   c("FALSE",
"TRUE"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class =   "data.frame")

I got the error:
**Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) :
'.' in formula and no 'data' argument**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO, you should post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), or the output of `dput(wifilocDat)` or if it is too large `dput(head(wifilocDat,20))`. Also include the package you are working with in the code with `library(...)`. However, if you use a formula you don't need to write `Train$Loc3~.` you can directly write `Loc3~., data=Train`

Comment: Thanks Elia. I've added the requested information

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, but in this form, your data are not reproducible. You have to post the OUTPUT of dput(head(wifilocDat,20)), so we can copy-paste it to reproduce exactly your dataset.

Comment: Thank you Elia, I've updated per your comment.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with your code: first of all, I don't think it is a good idea to split your data in training and test based on the value of the outcome as you do. In that way, your training won't contain all the levels of the outcome, the same for the test set.

Here I post an example that works without problem (I had to add the missing level in the data because evidently, the first 20 rows of your data.frame did not contain TRUE values in the outcome):

```
#for the crateDataPartition function
library(caret)

#add some TRUE in the outcome
wifiLocDat$Loc3 <- c(rep(F,10),rep(T,10))
#transform back to factor
wifiLocDat$Loc3 <- as.factor(wifiLocDat$Loc3)
#create index for data splitting
ind <- createDataPartition(wifiLocDat$Loc3,p=0.7,list = F)
train<- wifiLocDat[ind,]
test <- wifiLocDat[-ind,]

set.seed(4343)
tune.out <- tune("svm",Loc3~.,data = wifiLocDat,kernel="polynomial", ranges=list(degree=c(1,2,3,4,5,6)))
summary(tune.out)
svmPoly <- svm(Loc3~., data=train, kernel="polynomial",coef0=1,degree = 3)
```

Here all it works with no problem.

However, with the sample data you posted I cannot reproduce your error, but when I run your code I get another error

> Error in predict.svm(ret, xhold, decision.values = TRUE) :
> Model is empty!

I think because you don't have all the possible values of the outcome in the training set

Comment: Thank you Elia. You pointed me in the right direction. I followed the steps you posted, and it worked.